# How to automatically generate triangles from vertexes in Unity3D, or how to acquire them from an STL file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am learning Unity3D meshes and I am trying to code my first project- STL viewer (working in runtime), based on Unity.
First of all, I created the code, which is parsing the STL file and removes all unnecessary text from it, and leaves the array of vertexes only. Then, I converted all the vertexes to an array of Vector3[]

[Inicial format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcwjV.jpg)
[Vector3 in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnGIQ.png)

Now I am assigning

mesh.vertices = vertices;

mesh.triangles = triangles;

Vertices seem to be fine, but I do not understand, how to get the triangles.
I was trying to assign them in order, like

123

456

789

but it does not seem to work, and I cannot find any description of triangles in STL format.
How can I get them from raw data or generate them from the vertexes I have? Assigning them manually does not seem to be an option, since there are thousands of triangles in stl, and the figures will be different every time

Answer (score 0):

Verteces between outer loop and endloop define one triangle. So you can do like you said, but start from zero

```
012
345
678
```

And you need normal, in order to display mesh correctly. There are 1 normal for triangle, so you need to copy it 3 times as normals array are the same size as vertices.